# JBoss EAP doesn't generate tables on specified database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss-eap-7

i have an issue when attempting to generate table with JBoss EAP 7.2.

My database is named KMT on MS SQL 2014, but when i run the JBoss EAP it creates the table in the system database named "master" despite I specified KMT in my connection-URL.

I created the datasource with the admin console of the JBoss EAP and when testing the connection i got a succes message.

My connection-URL:

```
JNDI Name: java:/MSSQLDS
Driver Name: sqljdbc42.jar
Connection URL: jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=KMT
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="KMT">
      <jta-data-source>java:/MSSQLDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally the entity I try to generate inside KMT database:

```
package be.Alstom.kmt.domaine;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="designer", schema="kmt")
public class Designer implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String userName;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public Designer() {
    }

    public Designer(String userName, String password) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((userName == null) ? 0 : userName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Designer other = (Designer) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (password == null) {
            if (other.password != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
            return false;
        if (userName == null) {
            if (other.userName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userName.equals(other.userName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Here the my MSSQL server. Hibernate create table in systemdatabase/master instead of KMT.